# Query to find the count of columns for all tables in impala/hive on Hue

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to fetch a count of total columns for a list of individual tables/views from Impala from the same schema.

however i wanted to scan through all the tables from that schema to capture the columns in a single query ?

i have already performed a similar excercise from Oracle Exadata ,however since i a new to Impala is there a way to capture ?

## Oracle Exadata query i used

```
select owner, table_name as view_name, count(*) as counts
from dba_tab_cols /*DBA_TABLES_COLUMNS*/
where (owner, table_name) in 
(
select owner, view_name 
from dba_views /*DBA_VIEWS*/
where 1=1 
and owner='DESIRED_SCHEMA_NAME' 
)
group by owner ,table_name
order by counts desc;
```

## Impala

Comment: So.... can you be more specific -- is it Impala or Hive?

Comment: @mazaneicha - Impala Tables are created on Impala schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hive v.3.0 and up, you have `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` db that can be queried from Hue to get column info that you need.

[image]

Impala is still behind, with JIRAs IMPALA-554 [Implement INFORMATION_SCHEMA in Impala](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-554) and IMPALA-1761 still unresolved.

Comment: Thanks it's nice to know , i have tried this in hive as well as in impala  SHOW CREATE TABLE <SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME>; -> this gives me the ddl like oracle DESC <SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME>